# How to style in java swing?

Tags: swing, coding-style, java

I`m very new to Java and I want to create a program and I already have some problems styling it. I want a simple program with the following structure:

The first line should be the menubar with file and about buttons.
In the second line I should have a text: "url: ", a text input (for the url) and a "go" button after the text input.
On the third line I need a tabbed menu with 3 tabs: tab1, tab2, tab3.

The rest of the content until the bottom of the window should be a table with rows and columns and it should have vertical and horizontal scroll bars if the content is too big and if the window is bigger than the table than it should fill the entire window.

For now I have only this code:

main.java :

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SEO Tool");      
        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        menubar menubar = new menubar(); 
        menubar.createmenubar_site(frame);

        tabs tabs = new tabs();
        tabs.createtabs(frame); 
    }
}
```

tabs.java :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class tabs {

    public void createtabs(JFrame frame){

        JLabel sitelabel = new JLabel("A");

        JPanel sitepanel = new JPanel();
        sitepanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sitepanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        sitepanel.setSize(400,400);
        sitepanel.add(sitelabel);
        frame.add(sitepanel);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        //panel.setBounds();
        frame.add(panel);

        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel yoursite = new JPanel();
        JPanel yourcompetitors = new JPanel();

        tabs.addTab("Your site",yoursite);
        tabs.addTab("Your competitors",yourcompetitors);

        panel.add(tabs);        

        sitetab sitetab = new sitetab();
        sitetab.createcontent(yoursite);    
    }
}
```

menubar.java :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class menubar {

    public void createmenubar_site(JFrame frame){

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);

        JMenuItem newproject = new JMenuItem("New Project");
        newproject .addActionListener(new click_newproject());
        file.add(newproject);
    }

    static class click_newproject implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I good at html and css - is there any way to style java components like html and css ?

Comment: Java is real programming. It's not like HTML, sorry. You'll have to use layouts to design. It's actually easier than HTML, IMO. Layouts range from simple, `FlowLayout`, to easy, `BorderLayout`, to more complex `GridLayout`, to very complex, `SpringLayout`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers, but I`we made it! :D I`m using Spring Layout and it`s actually easy.

Comment: Then you should select Nidu's answer as best. If it didn't help you, write your own answer so that someone who stumbles upon this with the same question will know how to sole it.

Comment: *"menubar with file and about buttons"*  Menus do not (or at least should not) contain buttons.  Noting that your code actually adds menus to the menu bar, my advice is.. "Type the descriptive words carefully - programming is a precise business and communicating problems to an international audience is already hard enough without being sloppy with terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the example of layout you described as i understood (i made it using NetBeans WYSIWYG - good tool, but you should understand layouts anyway). It doesn't use your code but can give you basic understanding of how it can be done. I would recommend you read more about layouts here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html .

```
private void initComponents() {

    urlPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    urlLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    urlField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    urlButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    tab1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    tab2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    tab3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    tableScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    table = new javax.swing.JTable();
    mainMenu = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    aboutMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(getContentPane(), javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    urlPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    urlLabel.setText("url:");
    urlPanel.add(urlLabel, java.awt.BorderLayout.WEST);

    urlField.setText("http://google.com");
    urlPanel.add(urlField, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    urlButton.setText("Go");
    urlPanel.add(urlButton, java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST);

    getContentPane().add(urlPanel);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout tab1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(tab1);
    tab1.setLayout(tab1Layout);
    tab1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        tab1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 395, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    tab1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        tab1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    tabbedPane.addTab("tab1", tab1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout tab2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(tab2);
    tab2.setLayout(tab2Layout);
    tab2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        tab2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 395, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    tab2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        tab2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    tabbedPane.addTab("tab2", tab2);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout tab3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(tab3);
    tab3.setLayout(tab3Layout);
    tab3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        tab3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 395, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    tab3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        tab3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    tabbedPane.addTab("tab3", tab3);

    getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

    tableScrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    getContentPane().add(tableScrollPane);

    fileMenu.setText("File");
    mainMenu.add(fileMenu);

    aboutMenu.setText("About");
    mainMenu.add(aboutMenu);

    setJMenuBar(mainMenu);

    pack();
}
```